# Autostart TeamSpeak via systemd under Ubuntu

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service script to let me start and stop TeamSpeak. It works fine if I manually start and stop it, but it won't autostart TeamSpeak on server reboot. Here's the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak Server
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh start
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh restart
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
PIDFile=/usr/local/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server.pid
User=smares
Group=smares

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The following script for my ARK: Survival Evolved server works fine:

```
[Unit]
Description=ARK: Survival Evolved Server
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/smares/Steam/games/ark/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGameServer TheIsland?MaxPlayers=5?listen -server -log
LimitNOFILE=100000
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s INT $MAINPID
User=smares
Group=smares

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The script works when I run it manually, but not when I try to start it on bootup" often suggests it's expecting an environment value it's not finding.

Comment: any chance to see `journalctl -u teamspeak` command output?

Comment: Appears to only contain the lines from my startup.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while setting up my TeamSpeak server on Ubuntu Server 16.04 and managed to solve it using the following systemd unit (saved to `/etc/systemd/system/teamspeak3.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak3 Server
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/teamspeak3-server
User=teamspeak3-user
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh start initfile=ts3server.ini
ExecStop=/opt/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
ExecReload=/opt/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh reload
PIDFile=/opt/teamspeak3-server/ts3server.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And by enabling this service like this:

```
systemctl enable teamspeak3.service
```

Since you didn't give the output of `journalctl -u teamspeak3.service`, it's hard to say what exactly was the problem. I've also tested my config with the same `After` as you specified and this also worked, so I assume the problem was either that you failed to correctly enable the service or that there was something wrong with the `.ini` file, because you didn't specify one in your `ExecStart` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak3 Server
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/teamspeak3
User=teamspeak
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/teamspeak3/ts3server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found using `Type=simple` better. This way systemd monitors the process and you also get the stdout output from the teamspeak server in the `journalctl` output.